# Debug Assertion Failed! Visual C++

Tags: c++

[image: My Error Code]

here is code.

```cpp
char* getURL() {
    char* urlstr;
    if FAILED(CoInitialize(nullptr))
        cout << "something error..." << endl;
    struct coinit { ~coinit() { CoUninitialize(); } } cleanup;

    //find the first visible window in firefox
    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    while (true)
    {
        hwnd = FindWindowEx(0, hwnd, (LPCSTR)"MozillaWindowClass", NULL);
        if (!hwnd)
            return 0;
        if (IsWindowVisible(hwnd))
            break;
    }
    //initialize UIAutomation
    CComPtr<IUIAutomation> uia;
    if FAILED(uia.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation))
        cout << "something error." << endl;

    CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> root, navigation, editbox;
    CComPtr<IUIAutomationCondition> c1, c2;

    //find root from hwnd handle
    if FAILED(uia->ElementFromHandle(hwnd, &root))
        cout << "something error." << endl;

    //find navigation bar as child of root
    uia->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId,
        CComVariant(L"nav-bar"), &c1);
    if FAILED(root->FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, c1, &navigation))
        cout << "something error." << endl;

    //find editbox under as descendant of navigation
    uia->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_AutomationIdPropertyId,
        CComVariant(L"urlbar-input"), &c2);
    if FAILED(navigation->FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, c2, &editbox))
        cout << "something error." << endl;

    //get the string in editbox 
    CComVariant url;
    if FAILED(editbox->GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_ValueValuePropertyId, &url))
        cout << "something error." << endl;
    //if (url.bstrVal) {
    //    wprintf(L"[%s]\n", url.bstrVal);
    //}

    if (url.bstrVal == NULL) urlstr = (char*)"None";
    else urlstr = _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(url.bstrVal);
    return urlstr;
```

i wanna get url from firefox tab.
I tried `__try`, but `Cannot use __try in functions that require object unwinding`.
I do not know where the error is coming from.
Can anyone tell me how I can prevent this error?
environments: Windows11, Visual Studio 2019

When I changed the library to not throw exceptions, I found that I was getting an error here.

```cpp
if FAILED(navigation->FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, c2, &editbox))
```

Comment: When something fails, you should probably not keep going. `return` or throw an exception.

Comment: First of all you should use a debugger to catch the crash and locate when and where in your code it happens. Then examine the values of all involved variables and the point of the crash. Do they all make sense?

Comment: *I do not know where the error is coming from.* -- `(Press Retry to debug the application)`.  Did you do that?

Comment: debugger: atlcomcli.h, 204 breakpoint.

Comment: Are all parameters and the reference to the navigation object valid? Mabe one of the previous calls failed and the navigation isn't a real reference to a COM object?!

Comment: I found that the error occurs when I hover the mouse over a tab and the title is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This debugging error might happen when you pass a smart pointer (CComPtr) to COM like so:

```
CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> root, navigation, editbox;
CComPtr<IUIAutomationCondition> c1, c2;

// Find root from hwnd handle
if (FAILED(uia->ElementFromHandle(hwnd, &root))) // Here, we pass an IUIAutomationElement as input.
cout << "Something Error." << endl;
```

When you pass a CComPtr as an input, you must release that smart pointer before using it again like so:

```
root.Release();
```

Not only for that smart pointer, but for any smart pointer you pass as an input you should release it before using again.
See this MSDN link: [Debug Assertion Error when debugging CComPtr](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/da2af9b8-9cfa-47e8-ae51-8867ee164993/debug-assertion-error-when-debugging-a-ccomptr-no-clue-as-to-why-it-gives-me-that?forum=vcgeneral)
Learn more about CComPtr and smart pointers here: [COM Coding Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/com-coding-practices)